# Connecting to mysql database using a python script from an Ubuntu VM terminal (socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known error)

Tags: command-line, server, python, mysql, azure

I am unable to connect to my testdb database in order to create a table in the database (as shown in the image 1 of the script) below. Using the same connection parameters, I was earlier able to connect to the Azure MySQL server to create the testdb server from the VM terminal but now I couldn't connect to the database to create a table.

[image: The python script]

The error message (as depicted by image 2) and stated below was generated. Please note that the database server connection was set to allow traffic from the public and from Microsoft Azure resources, yet my script couldn't execute successfully.

**The command & result**

```
azproj2@GL-AZ-PROJ2-VM:~/home/ubuntu$ python3 process.py
*********************** Processing File *****************************
File has been processed

Uploading to Azure Storage as blob: docproc.csv
inv-00001
Mar 31 2018

*************************************************************************
Creating table invoice
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 703, in open_connection
    addrinfos = socket.getaddrinfo(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
  File "process.py", line 42, in main
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=hostname, user=username, passwd=password, db=database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 294, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 169, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1217, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 575, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 723, in open_connection
    raise InterfaceError(
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '%-.100s:%u' (%s) (Warning: %u format: a number is required, not str)
```

Anyone with a possible solution?

[image: The error from the terminal]

Comment: Really looking forward to the right feedback.

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. The images are very small and hard to read and we cannot actually use them since we cannot copy any text from them.

Comment: Is there actually a DB server running at the host you mention? Is it listening at the default port?

Comment: There is a DB Server running at the host and it's listening at the default port 3306. I could connect via workbench but unable to connect from the VM terminal.

Comment: The `Warning: %u format: a number is required, not str` error message is pretty specific. It's looking for a number, such as a port. If you're passing the username, then your mask is likely malformed. `{IP}@{user}` vs `{IP}:{port}@{user}`